# I have a discrete distribution and want to know to what extent other samples differ from it, what is the right test?

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, python

This is kind of a basic stats question, but I want to make sure I am doing this right.

I have a distribution of objects. Specifically: 
    `array([   6072.,  112673.,  126874., 44366., 5384., 14697., 20323., 68197., 98024.,39483.,     103990., 18556., 32930., 23551., 6897.])`

I then have a lot of samples like [1,4,0,0,0,0...] (same length) and I'd like to know how far the samples are from the distribution above. Correlation doesn't really do it. 
[32,0,0,0,..] should be further away than [4,0,0,0...].

Comment: Your phrasing here: "* [4,0,0,0...] should be as far away as [32,0,0,0,..] but with lower significance*" suggests that your notion of distance or significance will have to change for it to make sense. I don't see how the two can be consistent as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a Chi-Square test.  Based on your initial distribution you calculate the proportion for each value.  Then with your new data you compute the expected value based on these proportions and the sample size.  Use the Chi-Square test to see test how different your observed values are from the expected values:

$$
\chi^2 =  \sum \frac{(O-E)^2}{E}
$$

More explanation in this video (I did not watch it entirely, but I'll assume it's correct): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL8hlkKZ75s

Answer (score 0):

Multinomial test, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as 'low quality' because of its length. At present, it's sort of a comment. Can you expand it a little bit to make it more of an answer?

Comment: It *is* an answer. The topic starter asked for a name of a statistical test.

Comment: I agree that it is an answer, that's why I didn't vote to delete it when SE's software automatically flagged it. However, it would be nice if you could expand it a little.